# Error in data frame creation in R in Spark using as.data.frame

Tags: sql, r, pyspark, sparkr

I am trying to convert SparkDataFrame to R data frame.

```
%python

temp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_df_r")
```

```
%r

temp_sql = sql("select * from temp_df_r")

temp_r = as.data.frame(temp_sql)
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(temp_sql) :
> cannot coerce class ‘structure("SparkDataFrame", package = "SparkR")’ to a data.frame

Sometimes I get error, it's still unknown why I get error sometimes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

I need more details. What environment do you use?

Comment: I was working with Databricks (ML Cluster).